# python read_excel absolute path

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having to work with a file set in a directory structure I cant change

I'm having issues with trying to get the right path structure in excel.

Any thoughts?

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'/vagrant_data/xxx - Internal Documents/02 Work Packages/17 xxx/05 BoM/xxx')


IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/vagrant_data/xxx - Internal Documents/02 Work Packages/17 xxx/05 BoM/xxx'
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add an extension. `filepath/xxx.xlsx`

Comment: @NielsHenkens: On Windows, maybe. OP's string would be perfectly valid syntax for an absolute path on a Unix-style file system. Even on Windows (or `cmd.exe` specifically), something like `/path/to/file` should be understood and would refer to that path, relative to the currently active drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to that folder via terminal and execute `pwd` in the same directory where your excel file.